# Java HTTP server response in utf8

Tags: java, http, utf-8

I have a http server that receive POST requests and fetches data from mysql database.
This is the relevant part of the server:

```
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
        JSONArray jsonArr = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(he.getRequestBody(), "utf-8");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String query = br.readLine();
        JSONObject postData=null;
        try {
            postData=Constants.parseQuery(query);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR:      SelectHandler,handle,parseQuery, on query: " + query);
        }
//      Object t=params.entrySet().
        try {
            query=Constants.getSelectQuery(postData);
            jsonArr = MySQLQueryExecutor.getInstance().getItems(query);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR:      SelectHandler,handle,getItems, on query: " + query);
        }

        String encoding = "UTF-8";
        String ret=jsonArr.toString();
        he.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=" + encoding);

        he.sendResponseHeaders(200, ret.length());
        System.out.println(ret);
        OutputStream os = he.getResponseBody();
        ret= URLDecoder.decode(ret, "UTF-8");
        os.write(ret.toString().getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
```

I can see that the server handles the request and sends a response, but on the client side I get an error.
The error is due to utf8 characters in the response (hebrew chars that when I omit them the error is gone).
How can I fix this? Is this a server or client problem?

Comment: `URLDecoder` is completely not what you want.  You need to write UTF8 bytes of the string.

Comment: os.write(ret.getBytes(encoding)); does not help if that what you meant

Comment: What response are you actually receiving?

Comment: I believe you need to use URLEncoder.encode while sending the response back.

Comment: I also tried the decoder and I still get a failure on the client. When I use postman I get "Could not get a response", while the server is sending a response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length is wrong too. A bit further will go:

```
    String encoding = "UTF-8";
    String ret = jsonArr.toString();
    he.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=" + encoding);

    //ret= URLDecoder.decode(ret, "UTF-8");
    byte[] bytes = ret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    he.sendResponseHeaders(200, bytes.length);
    System.out.println(ret);
    OutputStream os = he.getResponseBody();
    os.write(bytes);
    os.close();
```

Comment: ...but it still has a broken Content-Type.

Comment: The mime type should be just `application/json` or for a callback `application/javascript`. The charset is just for `text/...`.. The default for json _is_ UTF-8. Is there an `addResponseHeaders` to add two headers?

Comment: @JoopEggen FWIW, there are "application/*" media types that take a charset param (such as "application/xml"), but this is not the case for "application/json".

Comment: @JulianReschke that is new for me, almost unbelievable, thanks.

Comment: It worked for me by using `headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=" + "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 1):

a) You have a broken Content-Type header field. There is no charset parameter in application/json. See last sentence in https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7159.html#rfc.section.11

b) You need to send the bytes obtained from String.getBytes("UTF-8") and

c) That's also how to compute the content length (so after encoding as UTF-8 bytes, not before).

Comment: os.write(ret.getBytes(encoding)); does not work. I also removed the broken header. Still, same error.

Comment: Not sure if you meant it, but you wrote `Content-Tye` instead of `Content-Type`.

Comment: The Content-Type header is correct, you always can add a charset also for JSON mime type. Only the default encoding is UTF according to RFC 4627 so it is not needed here.

Comment: @ArneBurmeister - nope. See RFC 7159.

Comment: @JulianReschke As far as I know "shall" (RFC 7159 8.1) is not "has to be", but maybe I missed something

Comment: @ArneBurmeister -- read last sentence in https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7159.html#rfc.section.11

Comment: @JulianReschke interesting, was not aware of that. But in the wild the charset parameter is very common and typically also considered. At least I am not the only one overseen that note.

Comment: @ArneBurmeister I encourage you to file bugs when the charset param is used -- this way leads to broken interop.